# Is it possible to navigate in Google using only shortcuts?

Tags: google-search, keyboard-shortcuts

Gmail has amazing functionality, which enables to use it effectively with vim-like shortcuts. I'm wondering whether there are shortcuts for Google search page as well. Do you know which shortcuts could I use in Google search in order to use it more effectively?

Answer (score 2):

There are no shortcuts like in gmail (shift+?), but after you give a term in Google bar and hit enter you can hit the tab key and then navigate with the arrows up and down and when you hit the right arrow you can see the preview of the site. That is actually everything you can do.

There is a Google help page on keyboard navigation:
http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=de&answer=191139

Comment: Unfortunately, that link redirects for me to https://support.google.com/?hl=en#topic=1733202, and no content is displayed